# How to set the color for RatingControl stars in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have added a `RatingControl` in my UWP application. How can I set the color for filled and empty stars? Here is the code that I have added:

```
<RatingControl x:Name="MyRating" Value="3.5" Width="300" Height="200"  />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the default style of the `RatingControl`, you can find the following `VisualStateGroup`:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="ForegroundContentPresenter.Foreground" 
              Value="{ThemeResource RatingControlDisabledSelectedForeground}"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Placeholder">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="ForegroundContentPresenter.Foreground"
               Value="{ThemeResource RatingControlPlaceholderForeground}"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPlaceholder">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="ForegroundContentPresenter.Foreground" 
               Value="{ThemeResource RatingControlPointerOverPlaceholderForeground}"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverUnselected">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="ForegroundContentPresenter.Foreground" 
                Value="{ThemeResource RatingControlPointerOverUnselectedForeground}"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Set">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="ForegroundContentPresenter.Foreground"
                Value="{ThemeResource RatingControlSelectedForeground}"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSet">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="ForegroundContentPresenter.Foreground" 
                Value="{ThemeResource RatingControlSelectedForeground}"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

As you can see, the colors are based on resources like `RatingControlSelectedForeground`, `RatingControlPointerOverUnselectedForeground` etc.

You can either provide your custom overrides for these as separate resources, or you can edit the style of the control.

**Note - empty stars color**

Although it is not part of the template, you can customize empty stars color by modifying the `RatingControlUnselectedForeground` resource.

### Resource overrides

You can override the resources on the level of a single rating control, any parent or on the application level.

Override on `RatingControl` level will apply only to this single `RatingControl`:

```
<RatingControl x:Name="MyRating" Value="3.5" Width="300" Height="200" >
    <RatingControl.Resources>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RatingControlSelectedForeground" Color="Red" />
       <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="RatingControlUnselectedForeground" />
    </RatingControl.Resources>
</RatingControl>
```

You can do the override on any parent, like on the page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RatingControlSelectedForeground" Color="Red" />
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="RatingControlUnselectedForeground" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Or finally you can put it on application level if you add it in `<Application.Resources>` in `App.xaml`. Then it will apply to any `RatingControl` in the app.

### Alternative solution - Custom style

If you want more control and even better customization, you can directly edit the default `RatingControl` style and its template.
Right-click the `RatingControl` in Designer (or in Document Outline window) and select **Edit style**, then **Edit a copy**, set a custom name and location where the style should be placed and confirm with **OK**. This will create a copy of the default template of the control, where you can edit the `VisualState` `Setter` values to match your desired color scheme.

Also note, that you will still have to provide a custom resource for the **empty stars** (`RatingControlUnselectedForeground`).

Comment: Thanks.It works for the filled stars.but what about the empty stars

Comment: Awesome :-) . If it solved the question, please consider marking it as solution, so that the question is closed.

Comment: Can you please specify how to set the width and height of rating star?width and height property works for its border not for the stars

Comment: It would be better to mark this question as resolved and create a new question for this

Comment: Thanks! Finally I can change empty stars colors.